# How to get Google Advertising ID in Unity 2020.1?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-advertising-id

It seems that the way to access the advertising ID that worked in Unity3d 2019.4, [RequestAdvertisingIdentifierAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.RequestAdvertisingIdentifierAsync.html) is deprecated for android in the 2020.1 release.

How can I access the advertising id in that [version](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.RequestAdvertisingIdentifierAsync.html)?

Comment: May I ask how do you know it's deprecated?

Comment: Did you manage it? Please post a solution.

Comment: Patch notes also confirm https://unity3d.com/unity/beta/2020.1.0b14 "Android: Changed: Application.RequestAdvertisingIdentifierAsync does nothing now"

Comment: If all else fails you may be able to request it directly from the Google API. If so, the information in the question and answer on this page might be of use potentially: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582610/unity-android-get-google-play-advertising-id

Answer (score 1):

Manually call into Java:

```
    public static string GetAndroidAdvertiserId()
    {
        string advertisingID = "";
        try
        {
            AndroidJavaClass up = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = up.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");
            AndroidJavaClass client = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient");
            AndroidJavaObject adInfo = client.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("getAdvertisingIdInfo", currentActivity);
    
            advertisingID = adInfo.Call<string> ("getId").ToString();  
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return advertisingID;
    }
```